# If ValueQ is buggy, what alternative is there?

Tags: function-construction, hold, expression-test

The function `ValueQ` has been irritating me for a while. I can't find its use for anything. Inspect the following:

```
a;
b = 1;
c = "c";
DetermineIfValueAssigned[x___] := Table[ValueQ[{x}[[i]]], {i, Length[{x}]}];
DetermineIfValueAssigned[a, b, c]
```

Expected `Output`:

```
{False,True,True}
```

Instead, returns `Output`:

```
{True,True,True}
```

However, `ValueQ[a]` by itself does return the expected `False`.

**What's going on here that can be re-implemented to obtained the wished results**?

Comment: While `ValueQ` can be tricky it looks like your function construction is the problem here.

Comment: @Kuba How so? Consider this other example: `{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
  Dynamic@ValueQ[x]}`. Doesn't work neither.

Comment: `{x}[[i]]` - this is rather expected to change, isn't it?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag unless any behavior you've observed has been confirmed to be a bug.

Comment: @Kuba `ValueQ\@{a,b,c}` is not allowed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `ValueQ[a]` returns expected output and your function does not, how come have you decided to blame `ValueQ`?

There are two problems.

You don't prevent `b` or `c` from evaluation so before they get to `ValueQ` they are already evaluated to `1` and `"c"`.

You need to be more careful with what you put in `ValueQ`. If you have `ValueQ[{x}[[i]]]` it will clearly change to anything that is in `{x}`.

```
a;
b = 1;
c = "c";

foo // Attributes = {HoldAll, Listable};
foo[x___] := foo[{x}]
foo[x_] := ValueQ[x]

foo[a, b, c]
```

> {False, True, True}

`Listable` may not fit your general use case well so here is a way without it:

```
foo // ClearAll
foo // Attributes = {HoldAll};
foo[x_, rest__] := Flatten@{ValueQ[x], foo[rest]}
foo[x_] := {ValueQ[x]}
```